# How to read I-797c form (notice of action for H1B)

Tags: usa, h1-visa, foreign-employment

I am an Indian citizen and currently a resident of France (on Scientific/D visa until 30/04/2015). A university in the USA that hired me as a faculty recently petitioned for an H1B for me. I received the I-797C form from the USCIS notifying me/the university that the H1B application was submitted.

However, some details on page 1 of the I-797C form elude me. In the screen shot below (with personal details redacted), what exactly does "**Class Consulate / POE OCC 90**" signify?

A cursory search of the intergoogles revealed not much.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Immihelp](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/h1b/lca-occupation-codes.html) and [Department of Labor](http://www.doleta.gov/regions/reg05/Documents/eta-9035.pdf) OCC 90 is an occupation code:

> **OCCUPATIONS IN EDUCATION**
>
> 090 OCCUPATIONS IN COLLEGE AN UNIVERSITY EDUCATION
>
> 091 OCCUPATIONS IN SECONDARY SCHOOL EDUCATION
>
> 092 OCCUPATIONS IN PRESCHOOL, PRIMARY SCHOOL, AND KINDERGARTEN EDUCATION
>
> 094 OCCUPATIONS IN EDUCATION OF PERSONS WITH DISABILITIES
>
> 096 HOME ECONOMICS AND FARM ADVISERS
>
> 097 OCCUPATIONS IN VOCATIONAL EDUCATION
>
> 099 OTHER OCCUPATIONS IN EDUCATION

The rest seems to be more of an issue with [formatting the form](http://www.isss.umn.edu/H1BEmployment/I-797B.pdf) then anything else and should read:

`Class  |   Consulate / POE   |  OCC`

Comment: Thank you! However, I notice that my I-797c doesn't have a consulate on it. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @drN Because this is only to notify you that your application had been received.